# How to convert FirebaseVisionImage to a bitmap

Tags: android, android-vision

I am using ml kit for text detection . We pass in FirebaseVisionImage to a detector.

I need to set this FirebaseVisionImage to Image view. How can I extract hr  bitmap from FirebaseVisionImage

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`getBitmap()`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/common/FirebaseVisionImage.html#getBitmap()) method of `FirebaseVisionImage`

> **`getBitmap()`**

- Returns its `bitmap` representation.
- The image will be rotated to up-right if it's created with rotation info via `setRotation(int)`.